# Generation of Stub Class of WSDL using Maven

Tags: wsdl, wsdl2java

What We Have:

1. In our project we download the wsdl from nexus repository using maven.
2. Maven has been used for generating the stub class.
3. If we take a look into the stub class, it will have the WSDL path like  "C:\Documents\target...."

Now the problem is if we deploy this package in development server where this path have no relevance.

Logically what we are thinking as part of the solution:

1. WSDL should be part of our project directory
2. and generated stub class should take the project context path instead of the path mentioned earlier.

Hope that is what we have to do logically, if our thinking logically wrong please correct us.

What Solution we Need:

1. Putting the WSDL file in project path, and change the POM file so that it will generate the stub using the WSDL which have in local.
2. Generated path should refer the WSDL from project directory instead of "C:\Documents\target...."

Looking for your help and support.

Answer (score 0):

if you generated stub once. you need not to generate it again. 
as far as wsdl location is concern put it in your project and specify the location inside the program